# Service Worker not prompting to be registered - net::ERR_FILE_EXISTS

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker, web-push, push-api

I browsed through the other threads - there was no concrete answer.

I implemented a service worker for notifcations

```
http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/chrome-web-push
```

I checked everything - all scripts are in root, the keys are well implemented. However, I do not get prompted to allow notifs.

Console output reads:

```
GET https://mydomain/service-worker.js net::ERR_FILE_EXISTS
```

Note: I do have the correct URL (just changed it here).

What causes the service worker error? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

It isn't anything to worry about.  See the internal bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=541797 the TL'DR is that when Chrome tries to fetch a new SW if there is no change and thus nothing to install it throws this error message to indicate that state.  There is nothing that you need to do.